# Dynamically Create Variables Based on Binary Indicators in R

Tags: r, dynamic, refactoring, tidyr, dummy-variable

I have user-level data that looks like this:

```
ID  V1 V2 V3 V4
001 1  0  1  0
002 0  1  0  1
003 0  0  0  0
004 1  1  1  0
```

In the above example, I would like an elegant solution (likely using **tidyr**) to dynamically refactor this to appear as:

```
ID  Num_Vars Var1 Var2 Var3
001 2        V1   V3   NA
002 2        V2   V4   NA
003 0        NA   NA   NA
004 3        V1   V2   V3
```

*Note that this example is simplified and there are actually many variables. The point is to have code that detects how many variables should be created, based on the maximum number of 1s in Var1-VarX that are populated for any user.*

Comment: Sorry @hrbrmstr I spent a few hours on this a couple of weeks ago and had given up on it, but then just decided to make a StackOverflow account instead (new to this). I was trying gather and spread (and some silly attempts at for-loops), but missing the steps in between. PS enjoyed your talk at the RStudio conference!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feels like some fairly standard reshaping: convert to long, manipulate by group, convert back to wide:

```
df %>%
    gather(key = var, value = value, -ID) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(value != 0) %>%
    mutate(Num_Vars = n(),
           Var_Label = paste0("Var", 1:n())) %>%
    spread(key = Var_Label, value = var) %>%
    select(-value) %>%
    full_join(distinct(df, ID))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
# Groups: ID [?]
# 
#      ID Num_Vars  Var1  Var2  Var3
#   <int>    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1        2    V1    V3  <NA>
# 2     2        2    V2    V4  <NA>
# 3     4        3    V1    V2    V3
# 4     3       NA  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

---

Using this data reproducibly shared with `dput()`:

```
df = structure(list(ID = 1:4, V1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), V2 = c(0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L), V3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), V4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gregor I was missing the steps in between your gather and spread. Can't accept your answer yet until I'm reputation 15 (this was my first question), but I'll make sure to once I am!

Comment: You shld be good-to-go for accepting now :-) Also: rly nicely done example @gregor.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.var = "ID")[, Num_vars := sum(value), 
   ID][value!=0][df[, "ID", with = FALSE], on = "ID"], 
   ID + Num_vars ~ paste0("Var", rowid(ID)), value.var = "variable")
#    ID Num_vars Var1 Var2 Var3
#1:  1        2   V1   V3   NA
#2:  2        2   V2   V4   NA
#3:  3       NA   NA   NA   NA
#4:  4        3   V1   V2   V3
```